# Global unique identifier for WinForms/WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, winforms, ui-testing, ranorex

For test automation purposes I would like to target specific UI controls in WinForms and WPF applications in a fast and resilient fashion. Currently I find myself using XPath to achieve this goal and it is brittle and slow. Ex:

```
  /form[@controlname='frmPayloadDims']/container[@controlname='pnlAdajacent']/container[@controlname='grpThruster']/checkbox[@controlname='chkMegaJoulInclinationDeg'] ...
```

I'm looking for a better solution, perhaps similar to the HTML DOM's [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) attribute. There, model elements are available directly through their unique ids without having to build long paths.

Is there a global, unique and stable (across app restarts) identifier that I can set on controls when coding them so that I can use it to directly address them from Ranorex or similar UI automation tools?

Comment: Both WinForms and WPF are UI Automation-compliant and expose accessibility object. You van reach/search UI elements by AutomationId, Name (the Text of n element), Type, Role etc, or AccessibleName / AccessibleRole etc., group/discriminate based on their specific containers, or, as mentioned, by Role and Type, or because specific Patterns are exposed / implemented. Walking the Tree is pretty simple and search patterns can make use of Conditions that also support `AND`ing, `OR`ing etc. -- If you're used to WPF, you'll find it even more close to home.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi. I'm looking for a solution that eliminates any tree searches and provides direct access. A global hashmap of sorts. I'm wondering how slow a single, up front DFS would be, test-side.